# Listing QuickBooks customer information in web app using QWC

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am writing a simple web application that needs to retrieve a list of customers from QuickBooks and display it in a DataGrid.  I have the web connector installed and setup on the server hosting the QB data file using the web service example included in the SDK.

I can add the service to my project and interact with it, but when I try to find information about how to query QB using the web service all I can find are links to vague and mostly useless documentation.  What I’m hoping someone here can do is provide a real example (code included) of how you submit a query to QB and display the results.

My environment:

- QuickBooks 2009 Pro
- IIS 7
- C#.Net 3.5

Normally I have good success doing things like this, but for some reason this one has me stumped.  Many have suggested that I should run far and fast from anything that involves integrating QuickBooks with anything.  Come cant, it can’t be that hard.

As always, thanks in advance for any help you may offer.

Comment: Hi Bert, i'm having same problem .. did you get answer ..? please help me i need same thing..

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the official developer's guide?
http://developer.intuit.com/uploadedFiles/QuickBooks_SDK/QBSDK/QBWC_proguide(1).pdf

What looks easiest in this scenario, if you have experience working with other odbc data sources in C#, would be to use an ODBC implementation of the QB data. I'm not sure if there are others, but there is a commercial one (with a free trial) available here: http://qodbc.com/

Comment: Yea I've looked at the guide with little success of making heads or tails out of it.  More of a learn by example kind of guy.  I did think about the QODBC solution but the web app will be hosted offsite from the quickbooks server and I wasn't real sure of the impact on performance and/or security.

Comment: @Bert, integrating with an ODBC data source should be super-fast to prototype. If purchasing the QODBC library is a viable option, I'd test out the trial version to see if it will stand up to your performance requirements.

Comment: I'll give it a deeper look, but would still like to get the web connector doing it's thing.  Just seems like the right way to do it.

Comment: Just to let everyone know I found this great Framework for woking with the QuickBooks Web Connector. 

http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_vbdotnet_consolibyte

Comment: Nice! Glad you found what you needed.