# asp.net application integration with quickbooks using odbc driver

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc, quickbooks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listing QuickBooks customer information in web app using QWC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552272/listing-quickbooks-customer-information-in-web-app-using-qwc)

I want to integrate my asp.net web application with quickbooks for getting items information.I have installed the quickbook odbc driver.Now i don't understand how to get the items information in my c# class.I want to write a method where i want to get the items info using odbc driver but i dont see any example in asp.net to accomplish this task.
Any help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552272/listing-quickbooks-customer-information-in-web-app-using-qwc which is probably an existing, near duplicate, question.

Comment: Since there is no real answer to the other 3 versions of your question: Take a look at [Creating Connections to ODBC Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from Microsoft.  You should be able to use the QBODBC driver in the same way as the MS one, the only differences will be in the exact methods available.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the question above- the question above is about the QuickBooks Web Connector, which is a SOAP-based protocol for accessing QuickBooks data. This user is asking about the QODBC ODBC database driver for accessing QuickBooks. They are two VERY different technologies, and thus two VERY different questions.